# When does observeValueForKeyPath get called?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Does it get called after a property is changed (meaning property setter is already popped from call stack) or when a property setter is executing?

Swift has very handy `"Property observers"`. Does Obj-C have something similar for KVO?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what options were used when the observer was added. If the observer was added with `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior`, then `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` is called both before and after the property is changed. Or, more accurately, it's called both during the `-willChange...` and during the `-didChange...` methods.

If `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior` was **not** used, then `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` is only called after the property is changed. (During the `-didChange...` method.)

Swift property observers aren't really similar to KVO. Rather, they are more like implementing the property setter yourself (or overriding it in a subclass) and doing something before and/or after actually changing the instance variable that backs the property (or calling through to super).

I recommend against writing a class that uses KVO on its own properties to respond to changes. Instead, it should implement the setter to do something when a property changes.

Answer (score -2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:

The link above should be what you are looking for. It is apples docs